# Show Play Music's 'now playing' notification on Windows PC

Tags: windows, google-play-music

At my desk, while working, I typically stream music from Google Play Music (GPM) using my Chromecast Audio device linked up to my hifi. I control this via my Samsung Galaxy S5.

What I'd like is some way to display the 'now playing' track on my Windows 10 laptop (as a widget or notification, preferably), as this is the screen that occupies my attention; I don't want to have to divert my attention from my work in order to turn the phone screen on every time the track changes.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this (I could conceivably script something if there was an appropriate API, but there doesn't seem to be). Or a way to send that info from the phone to the laptop?

Comment: There are a couple of tools that allow for display of your Android notifications on your desktop. Pushbullet is one that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

> First, make sure you have Google Chrome Chrome on your computer and
>   add the Cast button to your toolbar.
>
> Then, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open Chrome
> 2. Connect your computer and Chromecast to the same
>      wireless network
> 3. Go to Google Play Music (play.google.com/music)
>      using Chrome. You can also add the [Play Music chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg) and
>      cast from here instead
> 4. Click a song, album, or playlist
> 5. Click the play icon
> 6. Near the bottom of the screen, click the cast icon. It will be next to the playback controls
> 7. Under "Connect to a device", select your Chromecast from the device list.
>
> **To disconnect:**
>   Near the top right of your browser, touch the cast icon Cast > Stop
>   casting.
>
> **Playback controls:** You can use the playback controls on Google Play
>   Music, near the bottom of the screen.
>
> Note: You may want to keep the music player open when casting music
>   from your computer. Playback controls can't be used after the music
>   player has been closed, the computer has been turned off, or an
>   Internet connection has been lost.

Source: [Use Google Play Music with Chromecast](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/4415504?hl=en)

Comment: yes, this is one option; but I have a feeling this solution doesn't allow the Chromecast to play the stream direct from the web source? Also, I dont do all my work in a browser - a notification would be better.

Comment: @fearoffours It does play it directly from the web source, as you can close the browser after you start the cast, though you would no longer be able to control it. This is currently the only way to cast GPM.